# Посоветуйте библиотеку python 3 для аппроксимации и экстраполяции

Tags: python, математика, библиотеки, анализ-данных, интерполяция

Имеется набор точек x,y. Необходимо произвести аппроксимацию и экстраполяцию кривой, соединяющей данные точки, на языке python 3.10. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую библиотеку удобнее для этого использовать, где есть данный функционал?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html

Comment: Ещё https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html